# What collection is this?

Tags: theory, scales, modes

Does the following collection represent a Gregorian chant mode, or is it a scale?

[image: Gregorian mode?]

<sup>(cf. "[How to know if it's a mode or scale?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/12131/28419)" or [these resources on the 8 modes of chant](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/search?query=id:5977%20or%20id:5978%20or%20id:5974%20or%20id:5975%20or%20id:3332%20or%20id:3327))</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the C-Dorian scale. We know this because Dorian lowers the third and seventh of the major scale, so from C major:

`C D E F G A B`

we just lower the third and seventh (E and B) to get the collection you posted.

(Dorian is also the natural minor scale with a raised sixth, if you want to go that route. You'll get the same result.)

As for whether or not it's a mode or a scale: in this case, it's kind of both. (It's a bit like how a square is a rectangle, but not all rectangles are squares.) This is a **scale** of the C-Dorian **mode**.

With such little context, I think it's better to ask "What collection is this?" instead of "Is this a mode or a scale?"

---

**Edit:** Just to add some further clarification, a *mode* is often understood as a *rotation* of a scale. So if we take the B♭-major scale:

`B♭ C D E♭ F G A B♭`

we can "rotate" it to begin on different members of that scale. If you rotate to start on C, you get:

`C D E♭ F G A B♭ C`

the exact same C Dorian from your question.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at this is that all of the notes belong in a major scale and key. The key of Bb major. When a set of notes starts and centres on the second note of the major scale, it's known as Dorian mode. And because this set starts on C, it's C Dorian. Please note - it's *not* known as Bb Dorian - for reasons Richard has noted.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scale in the Dorian mode transposed down a whole step (C → B♭).

<sup>([source](http://forum.musicasacra.com/forum/discussion/comment/180403#Comment_180403))</sup>